# Unable to access trilogy sites and Meta

Tags: support, stack-exchange

I'm sorry if this belongs on Meta. From one of my computers (a laptop) I can not access StackOverflow, ServerFault, SuperUser, nor Meta. I can access the [StackOverflow blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com) and [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com). I can access seemingly all other accessible sites on the Internet. I can access these sites from other computers on the network. The problem occurs at both home and work (i.e., in both places, from my laptop I can access the above sites but I have a desktop in each place that can access these sites). I tried from a friend's house too; we can access StackOverflow from his computer but not from my laptop.  The problem occurs in both IE and Chrome. I had previously been able to access these sites from this laptop. All relevant systems are Windows XP or Windows Vista. In particular, the laptop is Windows XP. This has been occurring for about a week. What could be causing this?

The error message in IE is

While trying to retrieve the URL: https://stackoverflow.com/

The following error was encountered:

We can not connect to the server you have requested.

This means that:

- The server might be busy at this time.
- The server is not reachable.

Please try later to see if you can go through.

Edit: This problem has now spread to other machines on my team. My internal IT department is useless. If anyone has any ideas I am all ears.

Comment: Yep - belongs on meta. Though it'll probably be marked [status-norepro]

Comment: @ChrisF: Yeah, I can see that.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you run `nslookup stackoverflow.com` from a cmd prompt?
What happens if you run `tracert stackoverflow.com` from a cmd prompt?

Comment: `nslookup stackoverflow.com: Server: elided Address: elided Non-authoritative answer: Name: stackoverflow.com Address: 69.59.196.211`. If I run `tracert` from a computer that can access http://stackoverflow.com I can see the route until it hits what I think is my company's proxy server; after that I think the corporate firewall blocks the replies. If I run `tracert` from my laptop it does not make it past the first hop; that is, all requests time out. I realize that this will be difficult to diagnose since clearly something bad is happening internally, but any ideas where to start looking?

Comment: Strangely, the second machine that I was using that I could access http://stackoverflow.com from can now no longer access http://stackoverflow.com yet `tracert` still succeeds.

Comment: @jason are you at work?  Is it possible they've blocked your access to the site at the gateway/proxy level and that you're earlier observation that it was working from the other machine had to do with cacheing?

Comment: No, I've already investigated that possibility. Moreover, the behavior is not consistent with that possibility as sometimes I can access from one machine, sometimes from another, sometimes from both and sometimes from neither. Today I happen to have access from a desktop I have access to but not from my laptop. A few days ago I had access from my laptop for a few hours but not from the desktop. Yesterday I had access from neither.

Comment: So... it's a poxy proxy problem?

Answer (score 0):

You failed to mention what operating system your laptop is running.  Either way, let's have a look at your DNS settings.

Under Linux, have look at `/etc/resolv.conf` for DNS settings that may be causing the problem.

Under Windows, have a look at `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\` and run `ipconfig /all` and look for DNS settings that may be causing the problem.

Good luck!

Comment: Windows XP. There are no unusual entries in `hosts` etc. The DNS settings from `ipconfig /all` are identical to that for a machine from which I can access the sites.

Comment: @Jason The results of ipconfig /all shouldn't be "identical" to any other machine.  The MAC address and the ip address of this computer should be different for instance.

Comment: @Michael Pryor Jason said "DNS settings from ipconfig /all are identical" in his comment.  The MAC and IP address are not DNS settings.  Jason made no mention of the MAC and IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to flush your dns?  On windows, do: `ipconfig /flushdns`  After this, try again.

I'm not sure how this would be accomplished on Linux/Mac.

Comment: Yes I tried this and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

It could be browser related, especially if you are using Opera with "Turbo" mode.

Alternatively, I wonder if you've picked up an IP address that has previously been a repeat address for one of our less clement guests. IP blocks are very rare, but do happen. Only Jeff and the team know for sure, so e-mail team@stackoverflow.com.

I would check SO for any obvious cross-over, but it is down for maintenance at the moment.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Ugh, I'd hate to find out that someone at my company is one of those less clement guests. I'll take your suggestion and email Jeff. Thanks.